# Kotlin - How to extact specific data from JSON

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I know there is similar questions but none of them worked:

i want to parse this json:

```
{
"validacion": {
        "error":false,
        "mensaje":"ok",
        "severidad": 0
},
"contenido": {
    "salidaTransferencia":[{
        "FolioEntrega":251943,
        "FechaDist":"22/01/2020",
        "Hora":"16:40:29",
        "Almacén":108,
        "Descripción":"CEDIS León",
        "nEstatus":2,"Existencia":"NO"
    }],
    "salidaEntregaClientes":[]
} }
```

into my class "DbValidatorContent",
this the code:

```
open class DbValidatorResponse (
@SerializedName("error") var error: Boolean = false,
@SerializedName( value = "message", alternate = ["mensaje"]) var message: String = "",
@SerializedName("type", alternate = ["severidad"]) var type: Int = 0 ): RealmObject()

open class DbValidatorContent (
@SerializedName( value = "validation", alternate = ["Validacion, validacion"]) var validation: DbValidatorResponse? = null,
@SerializedName( value = "content", alternate = ["Contenido, contenido"]) var content: String = ""): RealmObject()
```

Why im doing it like this? Because i dont want to make another class for every single response i get from the server that includes DbValidatorResponse. So, "contenido" is a string to work with it later.
The response from the callback is type "ANY"

My GET function:

```
fun inquiryPendingMoves(nCodAlmInterno: Int, bCancelado: Boolean): MutableLiveData<DbValidatorContent> {
    var mResponse = MutableLiveData<DbValidatorContent>()

    cloudApi.inquiryPendingMoves(nCodAlmInterno, bCancelado).enqueue(object :
        Callback<Any> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<Any>,
            response: Response<Any>
        ) {
            Log.e("READ_CAPTURE_RESPONSE", "ResultCode: " + response.code())
            Log.e("READ_CAPTURE_RESPONSE", "Message: " + response.message())
            Log.e(
                "READ_CAPTURE_RESPONSE",
                "Content: " + Gson().toJson(response?.body())
            )

            try {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    var strBody = Gson().toJson(response?.body())
                    val jsonString = JSONObject(strBody)
                    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

                    // This is what im trying to do, but it crash
                    mResponse.value?.validation = gson.fromJson(jsonString.get("validation").toString(), DbValidatorResponse::class.java)
                    mResponse.value?.content = jsonString.get("content").toString()
                } else {
                    mResponse.value?.validation?.error ?: true
                    mResponse.value?.validation?.message ?: response.message()
                    mResponse.value?.validation?.type ?: 2
                    mResponse.value?.content ?: null
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e("EXCEPTION", "catch: " + e.message)
                mResponse.value?.validation?.error ?: true
                mResponse.value?.validation?.message ?: e.message
                mResponse.value?.validation?.type ?: 2
                mResponse.value?.content ?: null
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Any>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("READ_CAPTURE_RESPONSE", "onFailure: " + t.message.toString())
            mResponse.value?.validation?.error ?: true
            mResponse.value?.validation?.message ?: t.message.toString()
            mResponse.value?.validation?.type ?: 2
            mResponse.value?.content ?: null
        }
    })
    return mResponse
}
```

Interface:

```
@GET(AppConstants.URL_INVENTORIES_INQUIRY_PendingMoves)
fun inquiryPendingMoves(@Query("nCodAlmInterno") nCodAlmInterno: Int,
                        @Query("bCanceladas") bCanceladas: Boolean) : Call<Any>
```

I'm new to Kotlin, what am I doing wrong and how can I achieve it?

Comment: can show your retrofit class?

Comment: The interface? i just added it.
Im learning on the run.. so, sorry in advance if you mean other thing

Comment: `Callback<Any>` and `Gson().toJson(response?.body())` are useless; use GSON or Moshi converter auto-mapping instead. Why would one define model classes and then expect `Any`? That's not the idea of ORM.

Comment: i do have classes for "salidaTransferencia" and "salidaEntregaClientes".
But, i dont want to create a new class for every response i get from the DB, thats why "content" is a string to extract a Json and parse the data on the run

Instead, i want to create a generic function to get "DbValidatorContent ". 
In the setter of inquiryPendingMoves i want to extract the other propertys of "Content" using their respective model classes.

Comment: If i cant figure it out, i will just copy the style of what it seems everyone else do; create a new model class for every single one response.... thats a looot of work, cant it be dynamic? In .net all i have to do is create a dataset and im ready to work without creating a model class.

Comment: Because android entity is type-safe. If you don't want to store these value in pre-defined data class, you have to get your result as `JSONObject` then cast them in any format that you want. But make sure to put a `try..catch` in between to avoid any exception.

Comment: And... with any i get a response, meanwhile changing the class response as "DbMovPendientes" only gets me null. Seriously, i've never have this many difficulties working with any language and it getting me on my nerves